# Slick2d and opengl blending - java

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, overlapping, blending

i have been working away trying to figure this out. I am currently coding a game using lwjgl and slick2d in java and i cant figure out how to make a pitch black room with a light following my player. I have tried everything and now am turning to the experts :P

[image: First]
[image: Second]

This first image would follow my characters x+width/2 and y+width/2 coords and the second would be the tile he is walking on. i would like it to look something like this.

[image: Third]

i had thought it had to do with blending as i seen another post relative to this but i am not %100 sure. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: It's look like a job for [shader](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=GLSL_Shaders_with_LWJGL), but I'm not an openGL expert ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching around and found out about fbo's ... all i had to do was make an fbo with my lighting in it and use gl blend to make the white alpha. The lwjgl page on fbos is terrible but this one made it a bit easier

[Simple Java FBO](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=32866.0)